# How to use OS Terrain 50 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem

I am new to GIS and I wish to perform view shed analysis of wind turbines from a DEM.

I have downloaded OS Terrain 50 and the data is contained within numerous zipped folders.

I am using a Mac with OS X Mavericks and I would like to know how to unzip all the data and merge them into one file for QGIS?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a guide posted [here](http://www.landscape-laboratory.org/2013/06/19/getting-started-with-os-terrain-50-elevation-data/) on the Landscape Laboratory blog (which requires use of the Mac command line):

> The data comes as a zip file containing a folder for each major OS grid square, further broken down in many (2,800+) zip files each containing a single 10 x 10km .asc elevation file. For example:
>
> `terr50_gagg_gb.zip/data/tq/tq00_OST50GRID_20130401.zip/TQ00.asc`
>
> Unfortunately, even with a SSD drive, unzipping all the zip files, as recommended in the user guide, took around an hour and just under 1gb of disk space. Luckily, there is a way to keep these further zip files compressed after the first, main zip file has decompressed and create a single, lean file of the entire British Isles for quick and convenient use in your GIS using the Terminal and GDAL.
>
> The elevation data is ultimately stored in .asc files. I made a list of all the .asc file names stored within the zip folders by decompressing all the individual zip files then running the following command from the /data/ folder with the Terminal (OS X in my case):
>
> `find . -name "*.asc" > ~/GB.txt`
>
> this outputted a text file listing each individual .asc file. Here’s an excerpt:
>
> `./data/tq/tq00_OST50GRID_20130401/TQ00.asc
>   ./data/tq/tq01_OST50GRID_20130401/TQ01.asc
>   ./data/tq/tq02_OST50GRID_20130401/TQ02.asc
>   ./data/tq/tq03_OST50GRID_20130401/TQ03.asc
>   ./data/tq/tq04_OST50GRID_20130401/TQ04.asc`
>
> To save yourself this time consuming stage, the text file I generated is available [here](http://www.landscape-laboratory.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/gb.zip) (note to Ordnance Survey, it would be great if you provided something similar with future releases!). If you carried out the first step the unzipped folders can now be deleted. With a couple of find/replace commands within a text editor, the file paths were altered to
>
> `/vsizip//[path]/terr50_gagg_gb/data/tq/tq00_OST50GRID_20130401.zip/TQ00.asc
>   /vsizip//[path]/terr50_gagg_gb/data/tq/tq01_OST50GRID_20130401.zip/TQ01.asc
>   /vsizip//[path]/terr50_gagg_gb/data/tq/tq02_OST50GRID_20130401.zip/TQ02.asc
>   /vsizip//[path]/terr50_gagg_gb/data/tq/tq03_OST50GRID_20130401.zip/TQ03.asc
>   /vsizip//[path]/terr50_gagg_gb/data/tq/tq04_OST50GRID_20130401.zip/TQ04.asc`
>
> where ‘[path]’ is the file path to the terr50-gagg-gb folder. Note that ‘/vsizip//’ and the ‘.zip’ extension were included to allow GDAL to read the many individual .asc files whilst they remain zipped and combine them into a single ‘virtual raster’ mosaic. This edited .txt file can then be fed into GDAL build virtual raster program:
>
> `gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list ~/GB.txt ~/GB.vrt`
>
> After a very short time the resulting .vrt file is 1.3mb, and accesses the partially compressed terr50 folder that now only occupies 160mb or so disk space. Most importantly, the .vrt file loads into QGIS in a few seconds and can be used exactly like the .asc files would.

You will have installed GDAL alongside QGIS. Your copy of the GDAL build virtual raster will probably be located at `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Programs/gdalbuildvrt` depending on the version number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is much appreciated! I have created the text file but I am stuck at the next stage. I could not find 'gdalbuildvrt' anywhere in my computer so i redownloaded GDAL 1.11 complete with no luck. I then downloaded GDAL framework v1.11-0.4 and 'gdalbuiltvrt.cpp' has appeared in the downloads folder when i search for it. Is this the correct program? Also, how do I 'feed' the text file into this program to create the final merged image for qgis?

Comment: Did you download GDAL from [here](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks)? The default install will put GDAL right where I listed.

Comment: I didn't realise there are two library folders. Ive found it now. Please could you explain to me how i feed the text file into this program? When i open this program it says: FAILURE: No output filename specified.
logout

[Process completed] at the bottom, is this ok? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I'll assume your home folder is called 'will' and the file listing the tiles is called 'input.txt' and saved to the Desktop. You Open Terminal and type `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Programs/gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list /Users/will/Desktop/input.txt /Users/will/Desktop/output.vrt` The output, 'output.vrt' will be created on the Desktop when the command is run. the `-input_file_list` bit means, I'm feeding you a file with multiple listed within it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me, your answers are really helpful! I've sorted it now! In the latest edition of OS terrain 50, some of the file names are different, for example where some files used to be called 20130401.zip they are now called 20140717.zip so I had to create a new text document.

Comment: I've made available a full vrt file to save people the trouble of doing this (all being well). It's formatted for Windows so if someone can check what needs to be different to work on a different system we can add these details to the accompanying readme. Feedback welcome. See here: https://github.com/RW-gis/useful-stuff/tree/master/OS_resouces

Comment: Rostranimin, I have gone to the Github link but I think that the import file that needs to be edited for use in Windows is either missing or not hyperlinked. Apologies if I am wrong. I am looking for a tutorial to import Terrain50 data in to QGIS and I am stumped so any help you can provide in locating the missing file would be appreciated, please. I am a QGIS novice, regrettably. I have essen v2.14.21 in Windows 10. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sorbus has given an excellent answer (+1).  The VRT solution in Sorbus' answer is definitely the way to go, and QGIS will also read the compressed vector contour files too (after the initial decompression).  However, sometimes you may need access to the uncompressed data (e.g. if you are using something other than QGIS which doesn't support reading zipped gis files).  So, just for the sake of completeness here is an approach to recursively unzipping the entire Terrain50 dataset in one go (which took considerably less than an hour - though I forget exactly how long).

This method requires [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) which is available for Windows, Linux, Unix and Mac.  Unzip the downloaded file (it gives a folder containing subfolders named by maptile, which in turn contain various recursively zipped subfolders for both raster and vector contour data). Create a batch file (DOS example below - adapt to suit your OS) and save it in the topmost Terrain50 folder:

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%
    cd %%F
        FOR %%X in (*.zip) DO (
            "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%X"
        )
    popd
)
```

Obviously edit your path to 7Zip.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that will work in both the QGIS and ArcGIS Pro python consoles (*not* ArcMap though, sorry).  It reads the downloaded zip file and generates a GeoTIFF with the same name. You don't need to unzip anything, you just need to change the path to the downloaded zip.

```py
import os
import zipfile
from osgeo import gdal

gdal.UseExceptions()

# No need to unzip, GDAL can read directly from terr50_gagg_gb.zip
# and the zip files that are inside.
input = "/path/to/terr50_gagg_gb.zip"
output = input.replace(".zip", ".tif")

srs = "EPSG:27700"

# Get a list of the zip files inside terr50_gagg_gb.zip
zips = (z for z in zipfile.ZipFile(input).namelist() if z.endswith(".zip"))
vrts = []

for zip in zips:
    basename = os.path.basename(zip)[0:4].upper()
    # Build a nested /vsizip path using curly brace syntax e.g.
    # /vsizip/{/vsizip/{/path/to/outer.zip}/path/to/inner.zip}/file.extension
    asc = "/vsizip/{/vsizip/{%s}/%s}/%s.asc" % (input, zip, basename)
    # We can't just BuildVRT with the list of .asc files
    # as some are Float32 and some are Int16
    # So just make them all Float32 VRTs
    vrt = f"/vsimem/{basename}.vrt"
    gdal.Translate(vrt, asc, outputType=gdal.GDT_Float32)
    vrts.append(vrt)

vrt = f"/vsimem/terr50_gagg_gb.vrt"
gdal.BuildVRT(f"/vsimem/terr50_gagg_gb.vrt", vrts)
gdal.Translate(output, vrt, outputSRS=srs, creationOptions=["TILED=YES", "COMPRESS=LZW", "PREDICTOR=2"])
```