# OS terrain 50: .vrt from zip files

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

I tried to follow what was suggested in [How to use OS Terrain 50 in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110013/how-to-use-os-terrain-50-in-qgis), but I got the following problem:

- in spite of being generally able to generate `.vrt` files using `gdalbuildvrt` from unzipped `.asc` files, when I try to do it using `/vsizip/` the resulting `.vrt` seems corrupted;
- it only contains NaN values, as can be seen from the following QGIS screenshot:

  [image: croped image]

GDAL version: GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10

First few lines for a single `.asc` file input:

```
ncols 200
nrows 200
xllcorner 440000
yllcorner 1200000
cellsize 50
    -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9
```

First few lines of the corresponding output:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="200" rasterYSize="200">
  <SRS>PROJCS["British_National_Grid",GEOGCS["GCS_OSGB_1936",DATUM["OSGB_1936",SPHEROID["Airy_1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-100000],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-2],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.999601272],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49],UNIT["Meter",1]]</SRS>
  <GeoTransform>  4.4000000000000000e+05,  5.0000000000000000e+01,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  1.2100000000000000e+06,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -5.0000000000000000e+01</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Float32" band="1">
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">/vsizip/hp40_OST50GRID_20150709.zip/HP40.asc</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="200" RasterYSize="200" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="200" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="200" ySize="200" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="200" ySize="200" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

Does anybody know what might cause it?

Comment: Vsizip is required only if the rasters remain zipped. If you're using the .asc directly, do not include /vsizip/// in the file paths you feed `gdalbuidvrt`. Can you confirm that you're using it on zips? Also, it won't work on zip files within zip files (how the OS ship their data). Can you post a few lines of the input and output files from `gdalbuildvrt` and state your GDAL version installed please?

Comment: I confirm that I'm trying to use it from zip files. I also confirm that I did I first extraction and I am trying to use it on the "second layer" of zip files. I know that I don't need to use vsizip if the .asc is already extracted, and so far i was using gdalbuildvrt with an input file containing the paths of the extracted .asc and everything is all right that way; I would just like to skip one step and read from the archive directly. How many lines do you need? I notice that the comment limit is easy to reach. GDAL version is GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10

Comment: @Sorbus, the problem was easily solved: it was just a problem of relative / absolute path; when using `/vsizip/` it looks like that the path has to be absolute; if you use a relative one you won't get any error but the vrt will not be properly linked to the input file. Sorry for the loss of time.

Comment: I'm glad you've solved it! No problem.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster solved their own question as follows:

> The problem was easily solved: it was just a problem of relative /
>   absolute path; when using /vsizip/ it looks like that the path has to
>   be absolute; if you use a relative one you won't get any error but the
>   vrt will not be properly linked to the input file.

-quoted from comment by @Filoz